# How to pass a collection/array parameters to an Action

Tags: playframework

I am reading the documentation about the controller http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/controllers and I know how to define them on the controller side.

```
public static void show(Long[] id) {
    ...
}
or:

public static void show(List<Long> id) {
    ...
}
or:

public static void show(Set<Long> id) {
    ...
}
```

Now, how do I call the controller and pass the array ?
I tried

```
Application/show?id=1,2,3,4
```

it doesn't work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way is

```
Application/show?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4
```

There is also a solution using @As annotation for custom binding since 1.1:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/releasenotes-1.1#play.data.binding.As

Answer (score 3):

You pass them as normal HTTP parameters

```
Application/show?id[0]=1&id[1]=2&id[2]=3&id[3]=4
```

Comment: As far as I know you don't need [0].. simple 'Application/show?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4' will do the job.